# Formatting flexes in media queries

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I'm having issues formatting a bar I made. It works perfect on a desktop, but when I try to format it for a mobile device the arrow looking part >, looks for like an upside down L.

In my media query I have done this so far, but cannot figure out how to make it work right..

```
.forum_links_out {
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 8px;
    display: flex;
    height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: .5em;
}
.forum_links_out a {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    position: relative;
}
.forum_links_out a:first-child {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.forum_links_out a span {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    top: 4px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    z-index: 2;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #E0E0E0;

}
.forum_links_out a:last-child {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
.forum_links_out a:hover, .forum_links_out a:hover span {
    background-color: #A0A0A0;
}
.forum_links_out a:visited {
    color: #000000;
}
```

Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/vd4hcy43/

Comment: Please add a fiddle, so I can play with the code, where is your HTML ?

Comment: Can you please provide a working example using Embeded StackOverflow Snippet or at best [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)  (or put your code online elsewhere) so we could test it? It's really hard to tell what's going wrong without being able to see your code.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to paste the fiddle. It has been added.

Answer (score 1):

When you set your media query style you don't resize your arrow so it is bigger than your bar

[image]

so just resize it in your media like this:

```css
.forum_links_out {
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 8px;
    display: flex;
    height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: .5em;
}
.forum_links_out a {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    position: relative;
}
.forum_links_out a:first-child {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.forum_links_out a:after {
    content: '';
    width: 21px;
    height: 21px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    top: 4px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    z-index: 2;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #E0E0E0;

}
.forum_links_out a:last-child {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
.forum_links_out a:hover, .forum_links_out a:hover:after {
    background-color: #A0A0A0;
}
.forum_links_out a:visited {
    color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="forum_links_out"> 
    <a href='discussions.php'>Samsung</a>
 <a>Apple</a>
 <a>HTC</a>
 <a></a>
</div>
```

Notice that I'm using pseudo elements (`:after`) to set the arrow instead a dummy `span` in html, this way is more clear and you avoid unnecessary elements in the html .

Comment: I am having issues with just one thing on this. My third section, where HTC in here is actually named General Fantasy Football, but this name isn't static and is contantly changing. However, This name goes past the bottom border. I tried changing `padding: 10px 30px;` to `padding: 10px 35px;`, but it didn't help. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can change the padding to `padding: 0 15px 0 30px` and using `line-height` to center it vertically so when you string to split it will be hidden check this: https://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/k1rfy4kt/

Comment: mine still is cutting off the Football word of it.

Comment: Well, if you're referring to it is hidden when the resolution is low (mobile), that is what is supposed to happen because you have `display: flex` in `.forum_links_out` so `.forum_links_out a` will shrink and its content will be cutting off when it be bigger than the element. To fix it add `flex-shrink: 0;` to `.forum_links_out a`